# Converting arithmetic sequence to slice in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a neat way to convert an arithmetic progression of integers into a slice in Python? Perhaps a nice built-in function?

It seems like an easy problem, but it's basically a nightmare.

I'm only interested in non-negative integer inputs.

My best attempt so far:

```
def seq_to_slice(xs):
    if len(xs) == 0:
        return slice(0, 0)
    start = xs[0]
    if len(xs) == 1:
        return slice(start, start+1)
    else:
        step = xs[1] - start
        stop = xs[-1] + step
        if stop < 0:
            stop = None
        return slice(start, stop, step)
```

Comment: I tried with `xs = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` and convert the slice `s` back to a sequence: `result = list(iter(range(s.start, s.stop, s.step)))`. I have `xs` equal to `result`. Do you have a case where this is false?

Comment: @LucasS. Not that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll also need to fail if the sequence does not have a uniform step.

```py
def seq_to_slice(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return slice(arr[0], arr[0]+1)
    diff = [arr[num] - arr[num-1] for num in range(1, len(arr))]
    if max(diff) == min(diff):
        step = max(diff)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Sequence cannot be converted to slice')
    step = None if step == 1 else step
    min_arr = None if min(arr) == 0 else min(arr)
    max_arr = max(arr) + 1
    if step and step < 0:
        min_arr, max_arr = max_arr - 1, min_arr - 1 if min_arr else min_arr
    return slice(min_arr, max_arr, step)

seq_to_slice([1,2,5]) # Should fail
```